# pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields' error in installing

Tags: podfile

## here is my pod file

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MaterialUi' do
  # Pods for MaterialUi
pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
end
i tried all the possible solutions

## sudo gem install cocoapods

## pod repo update

butt every time i got this!
 ## Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
       Xcode : 11.3.1 (11C504)
         Git : git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MaterialUi' do
  # Pods for MaterialUi
pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons'
end
```

#### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"components/Collections/src/'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:37:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:29:in `subspec_by_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `block in specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:53:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288:in `initial_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210:in `start_resolution'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%22components%2FCollections%2Fsrc%2F%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.2` on target `MaterialUi` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem on Xcode 11.3.1 (Swift 5) but I use "ActivityIndicator" component, instead "Buttons", it looks like the last version of MaterialComponents-pod is broken.
The solution that I found, you have to use last available number of version of your component, like this:

```
pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator', '~> 107.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Couldn't find help from anywhere. Then I append tag and worked for me. Example: pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields', '~> 119.4.0'
Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try. its worked for me

pod 'MaterialComponents', :git => 'https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios', :branch => ENV['DEFAULT_BRANCH']